# Web Crawler (Spider) com ajax no JSF usando Node.js ou api JSoup no java

Tags: java, node.js, http, http-request, web-crawler

Tenho a tarefa de criar uma interface otimizada para monitor touch, pegando dados de um site (http://www.consultas.der.mg.gov.br/grgx/sgtm/consulta_linha.xhtml).

Esse site dá uma listagem de linhas de ônibus e consulta os seus horários, utilizando um auto-complete ajax.

Por se tratar de um órgão  governamental, a possibilidade de obter os dados de outra forma é quase nula.

Pensei em fazer um crawler em java ou node.js para ir na url de requisição, passar os parametros do site (inputs) e filtrar na resposta aquilo que eu preciso. Fácil! Só na teoria :(

Fiz uma requisição nessa url:

> http://www.consultas.der.mg.gov.br/grgx/sgtm/consulta_linha.xhtml;jsessionid=1820D695BDE4B916EC808F84BD1B335D

Usando esse cabeçalho http com o módulo webcrawler do node.js:

```
Accept:application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:457
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=1820D695BDE4B916EC808F84BD1B335D
Faces-Request:partial/ajax
Host:www.consultas.der.mg.gov.br
Origin:http://www.consultas.der.mg.gov.br
Referer:http://www.consultas.der.mg.gov.br/grgx/sgtm/consulta_linha.xhtml
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

E o form data abaixo, onde usei o número 6 como query para o autocomplete, o que no site trás uma listagem:

```
javax.faces.partial.ajax:true
javax.faces.source:form:tabview:campoBusca
javax.faces.partial.execute:form:tabview:campoBusca
javax.faces.partial.render:form:tabview:campoBusca
form:tabview:campoBusca:form:tabview:campoBusca
form:tabview:campoBusca_query:6
form:form
form:tabview:campoBusca_input:6
form:tabview:campoBusca_hinput:6
form:tabview_activeIndex:0
javax.faces.ViewState:-6275073363975845032:-2043218073946595619
```

Porém, foi essa a resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei também no java, usando o JSoup, más foi pior, retornou uma exception de lifecicle.

Fui pego na curva. Como fazer um webcrawler funcional nesse cenário?

Comment: Depois de postar a recompensa que vi o erro de português: *citado.

Comment: Já tentou usar Selenium? Não sem em Java nem Node, mas para Python e R ele possui uma boa interface. Como ele automatiza operações no próprio browser, deve funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado Daniel. Peguei um plugin do firefox para testar o selenium. E vi que ele tem api pro java. Como seria a extraçao de dados com Python? Pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Estou precisando fazer um Crawler do DER também, alguma evolução no problema? Ia ser de grande ajuda!

Comment: Rodrigo, tomei outro caminho. Como minha demanda era fazer um terminal de consulta ajustando a interface para touch, eu simplesmente modifiquei a página em tempo de execução usando uma extensão para criar macros emacs6 no chrome. Está atendendo bem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fazer crawler de aplicações JSF é praticamente inviável por uma simples razão: JSF é *stateful* - em 99.9% dos casos.

Isso significa que você não pode fazer uma requisição arbitrária para o site, senão... terá o erro de *lifecycle*. Isso porque o sistema armazena informações na sessão, a qual não estará presente quando fizer a requisição fora do browser.

Não tenho a solução para esta situação em particular, mas tecnicamente seria necessário você similar o uso real do sistema e não somente a requisição final. Isso pode ser facilitado se você fizer um acesso manualmente e monitorar as requisições usando a ferramenta do desenvolvedor. Mais ou menos como já fez, mas incluindo os passos anteriores e enviando o ID de sessão em todas as requisições.

> Nota: não é porque os dados estão disponíveis na Internet que você pode simplesmente capturá-los e colocar no seu site. Sempre verifique os direitos de uso dos dados.